# getting a sh.exe for every background task

Tags: c#, bash, cygwin, background-process

I am running about 30 processes in parallel started from a bash script using:

```
/MyApp arg1 arg2 &
```

Where /MyApp is softlink to c# executable.

I notice in tasklist that there is a "sh.exe" for each MyApp I start.

Is this expected? Or am I starting the tasks incorrectly?

Comment: Try using `exec /MyApp arg arg` and it will call your app without creating a new process.  You won't be able to return to the script though.

Comment: @JohnC So you would expect a sh.exe to be created for each new background job?

Comment: If you are calling it from a shell script then yes.  If you are calling it directly then possibly /MyApp is a shell script itself.

Comment: No /MyApp is a c# executable - but I still get an sh.exe when called from script

Comment: When you put it in the background you spawn another shell. `&` does that.  Try putting an `exec` in front of your command as I first suggested.

Comment: OK, exec appears cleaner - no sh.exes and work the same way for me. Any downside I should look out for?

Comment: Nope not in this case I think you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your command with exec, e.g.:

```
exec /MyApp arg1 arg2&
```

This will cause the /MyApp to replace the shell and then run in the background and you won't see an extra shell being spawned with every command.